# How to Click on group if child is empty in expandable listview android

Tags: android, android-listview, arraylist, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have a problem in Expandable list view. Actually, the details for group and child are coming from server. There are some group that not contains any child element. so how we make that group Clickable and when on click move to an activity. It works fine when there is children for group and when on click on that child, it moves to an activity. Problem occurs when there is no child element in group.
Any help is deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance ... This is the activity class

```
public class NewsTabActivity extends Activity {

public static String Id, LOGO, WEB_SERV, SUB_CAT;
ImageView image;
ImageLoader imgloader;
String URL_MAIN_CAT, nDrawerSubCat, URL_SUB_CAT, URL_HOME_PAGE,
        URL_MAIN_CAT_ONLY;
String[] mainCatName, mainCatId, subCatParentID;
JSONArray jarray, jarray1;
JSONObject jobject, jobject1;

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView homeListview, headerListView;
private ExpandableListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

// nav drawer title
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;

// slide menu items
private String[] navMenuTitles;

ArrayList<NewsList> newsList;
private ArrayList<NewsDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NewsDrawerItem newsDrawerItems;

private ArrayList<NewsDrawerItem> listNewsHeader = null;
private ArrayList<NewsDrawerChildItem> listNewsChild = null;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<NewsDrawerChildItem>> listChildXXXXXXXXX = null;

NewsListAdapter adapter1;
private NewsDrawerListAdapter adapter;
private NewsDrawerHeaderAdapter adapterGroup;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hometab);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
    homeListview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    headerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_header);

    // homeListview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    // mDrawerList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    imgloader = new ImageLoader(NewsTabActivity.this);
    imgloader.DisplayImage(LOGO, image);
    nDrawerSubCat = SUB_CAT;

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NewsDrawerItem>();
    newsList = new ArrayList<NewsList>();
    listNewsHeader = new ArrayList<NewsDrawerItem>();
    listNewsChild = new ArrayList<NewsDrawerChildItem>();// ArrayList<ArrayList<ChildTerbaru>>>();
    listChildXXXXXXXXX = new ArrayList<ArrayList<NewsDrawerChildItem>>();

    System.out.println("DRAWER_SUBCAT ? = " + nDrawerSubCat);
    URL_HOME_PAGE = WEB_SERV + "homenews.php";
    URL_MAIN_CAT = WEB_SERV + "maincategory.php";
    URL_MAIN_CAT_ONLY = WEB_SERV + "maincategory.php";

    if (nDrawerSubCat.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
        URL_SUB_CAT = WEB_SERV + "subcategory.php";
        System.out.println("DRAWER_SUBCAT = " + URL_SUB_CAT);
    }

    if (nDrawerSubCat.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
        mDrawerList.setOnChildClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());
    } else {
        headerListView
                .setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickHeaderListener());
    }

    if (WebserviceUtils.isConnectingToInternet(NewsTabActivity.this))   {
        new NewsHomePage().execute(URL_HOME_PAGE);
        if (nDrawerSubCat.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
            new NewsPaperSubCat().execute();
        } else {
            new NewsPaperMainCat().execute(URL_MAIN_CAT_ONLY);

            // mDrawerList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // headerListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // adapterGroup = new
            // NewsDrawerHeaderAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            // navDrawerItems);
            // headerListView.setAdapter(adapterGroup);
        }
    }

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, // nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for
                                // accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for
                                // accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle("News Live");
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle("News Live");
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        displayView();
    }

}

/**
 * Slide menu item click listener
 * */
private class SlideMenuClickHeaderListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView();
        mDrawerList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        headerListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        NewsListActivity.valuesID(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());
        NewsListActivity.valueWEBSERV(WEB_SERV);
        System.out.println("NEWS_LIST_ID = "
                + navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());
    }
}

private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener,
        ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View view,
            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // if (nDrawerSubCat.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
        // displayView();
        // homeListview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // NewsListActivity.valuesID(navDrawerItems.get(groupPosition)
        // .getId());
        // NewsListActivity.valueWEBSERV(WEB_SERV);
        // System.out.println("NEWS_EXP_GROUP_LIST_ID = "
        // + navDrawerItems.get(groupPosition).getId());
        // } else {
        displayView();
        homeListview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        NewsListActivity.valuesID(listNewsChild.get(childPosition).getId());
        NewsListActivity.valueWEBSERV(WEB_SERV);
        System.out.println("NEWS_EXP_CHILD_LIST_ID = "
                + listNewsChild.get(childPosition).getId());
        // }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
            int groupPosition, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        displayView();
        // homeListview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        NewsListActivity
                .valuesID(navDrawerItems.get(groupPosition).getId());
        NewsListActivity.valueWEBSERV(WEB_SERV);
        System.out.println("NEWS_EXP_GROUP_LIST_ID = "
                + navDrawerItems.get(groupPosition).getId());
        return false;
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/* *
 * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
 */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView() {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    fragment = new NewsListActivity();

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        if (nDrawerSubCat.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(headerListView);
        }
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("NewsTabActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

private class NewsHomePage extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private ProgressDialog p_dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        p_dialog = ProgressDialog.show(NewsTabActivity.this, "",
                "Loading...Please wait...", true);
        p_dialog.setCancelable(true);
        p_dialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JsonParsor json = new JsonParsor();
        JSONObject jobject = json.getJSONFromUrl(URL_HOME_PAGE);

        try {
            JSONArray jarray = jobject.getJSONArray("news");

            for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jobj = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = jobj.getString("Id");
                String cid = jobj.getString("c_id");
                String title = jobj.getString("title");
                String image = jobj.getString("image");

                NewsList news = new NewsList();
                news.setId(jobj.getString("Id"));
                news.setCid(jobj.getString("c_id"));
                news.setTitle(jobj.getString("title"));
                news.setImage(jobj.getString("image"));
                newsList.add(news);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "sucess";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        p_dialog.dismiss();
        if (result.compareTo("sucess") == 0) {
            navDrawerItems.clear();
            adapter1 = new NewsListAdapter(NewsTabActivity.this,
                    R.layout.newslist_single_item, newsList);
            homeListview.setAdapter(adapter1);
            adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(NewsTabActivity.this, "No data Found...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}

   private class NewsPaperSubCat extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private ProgressDialog p_dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        p_dialog = ProgressDialog.show(NewsTabActivity.this, "",
                "Loading...Please wait...", true);
        p_dialog.setCancelable(true);
        p_dialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        JsonParsor json = new JsonParsor();
        jobject = json.getJSONFromUrl(URL_MAIN_CAT);
        // if (nDrawerSubCat.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
        jobject1 = json.getJSONFromUrl(URL_SUB_CAT);
        // }

        try {
            if (nDrawerSubCat.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                NewsDrawerItem LT = null;
                NewsDrawerChildItem CT = null;

                listNewsChild = new ArrayList<NewsDrawerChildItem>();

                jarray = jobject.getJSONArray("categories");
                // if (nDrawerSubCat.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                jarray1 = jobject1.getJSONArray("categories");
                // }

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jobj = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    mainCatName = new String[jarray.length()];
                    mainCatId = new String[jarray.length()];

                    mainCatId[i] = jobj.getString("Id");
                    mainCatName[i] = jobj.getString("name");
                    System.out.println("mainCatId[" + i + "] = "
                            + mainCatId[i]);

                    String id = jobj.getString("Id");
                    String name = jobj.getString("name");

                    System.out
                            .println("MAIN_ID = " + id + " NAME= " + name);

                    // adding nav drawer items to array
                    LT = new NewsDrawerItem(jobj.getString("Id"),
                            jobj.getString("name"));
                    listNewsHeader.add(LT);

                    // int listsize = listNewsHeader.size();
                    // for(int k=0 ; k<listsize; k++) {
                    // System.out.println("HEADER_VALUE["+k+"] = "+listNewsHeader.get(k));
                    // }
                }

                // if (nDrawerSubCat.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                for (int i = 0; i < jarray1.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jobj = jarray1.getJSONObject(i);

                    subCatParentID = new String[jarray1.length()];
                    subCatParentID[i] = jobj.getString("parent_id");
                    System.out.println("mainCatId_SubCatId[" + i + " = "
                            + subCatParentID[i]);

                    CT = new NewsDrawerChildItem(jobj.getString("Id"),
                            jobj.getString("name"));

                    System.out.println("SUB_MAIN_ID = "
                            + jobj.getString("Id") + " NAME= "
                            + jobj.getString("name"));

                    // if(mainCatId[i].contains(subCatParentID[i])) {
                    // String[] temp = new String[mainCatId.length];
                    // temp[i] = jobj.getString("Id");
                    // System.out.println("mainCatId_Temp = "+ temp[i]);
                    // }
                    List similarities = new ArrayList();
                    for (int j = 0; j < Math.max(mainCatId.length,
                            subCatParentID.length); j++) {
                        if (mainCatId[i] == subCatParentID[i])
                            similarities.add(mainCatId[i]);
                        System.out.println("VALU = " + similarities);
                    }

                    listNewsChild.add(CT);
                    listChildXXXXXXXXX.add(listNewsChild);
                }
                // }
            }
            // else {
            // jarray = jobject.getJSONArray("categories");
            //
            // for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
            // JSONObject jobj = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
            //
            // newsDrawerItems = new NewsDrawerItem();
            //
            // mainCatName = new String[jarray.length()];
            // mainCatId = new String[jarray.length()];
            //
            // mainCatId[i] = jobj.getString("Id");
            // mainCatName[i] = jobj.getString("name");
            //
            // String id = jobj.getString("Id");
            // String name = jobj.getString("name");
            //
            // System.out.println("MAIN_ID = " + id + " NAME= " + name);
            //
            // // adding nav drawer items to array
            // // navDrawerItems.add(new NewsDrawerItem(mainCatName[i],
            // mainCatId[i]));
            // }
            // }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "sucess";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        p_dialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (result.compareTo("sucess") == 0) {
            if (nDrawerSubCat.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                mDrawerList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                adapter = new NewsDrawerListAdapter(NewsTabActivity.this,
                        listNewsHeader, listChildXXXXXXXXX);
                mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(NewsTabActivity.this, "No data Found...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

private class NewsPaperMainCat extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private ProgressDialog p_dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        p_dialog = ProgressDialog.show(NewsTabActivity.this, "",
                "Loading...Please wait...", true);
        p_dialog.setCancelable(true);
        p_dialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JsonParsor json1 = new JsonParsor();
        JSONObject jObject = json1.getJSONFromUrl(URL_MAIN_CAT_ONLY);

        try {
            NewsDrawerItem NDI = null;

            JSONArray jarr = jObject.getJSONArray("categories");

            for (int i = 0; i < jarr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jObj = jarr.getJSONObject(i);

                mainCatName = new String[jarr.length()];
                mainCatId = new String[jarr.length()];

                mainCatId[i] = jObj.getString("Id");
                mainCatName[i] = jObj.getString("name");

                String id = jObj.getString("Id");
                String name = jObj.getString("name");

                System.out.println("MAIN_ID_ONLY = " + id
                        + " MAIN_NAME_ONLY= " + name);

                // adding nav drawer items to array
                navDrawerItems.add(new NewsDrawerItem(mainCatName[i],
                        mainCatId[i]));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return "sucess";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        p_dialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (result.compareTo("sucess") == 0) {
            mDrawerList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            headerListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            adapterGroup = new NewsDrawerHeaderAdapter(
                    NewsTabActivity.this, navDrawerItems);
            headerListView.setAdapter(adapterGroup);
            adapterGroup.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else
            Toast.makeText(NewsTabActivity.this, "No data Found...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public static void valueID(String id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Id = id;
}

public static void valueLogo(String logo) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LOGO = logo;
}

public static void valueWebService(String webServ) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    WEB_SERV = webServ;
}

public static void valueSubCat(String subCat) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SUB_CAT = subCat;
}
```

}

Here is the Expandable adapter class,

```
 public class NewsDrawerHeaderAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<NewsDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;

public NewsDrawerHeaderAdapter(Context context,
        ArrayList<NewsDrawerItem> navDrawerItems) {
    this.context = context;
    this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return navDrawerItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return navDrawerItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
    }
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

    txtTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(navDrawerItems.get(position).getId()));
    return convertView;
}
```

}

and here is the model class

```
public class NewsDrawerItem {

private String title, Id, PId;
private int icon;

private ArrayList<NewsDrawerItem> childItemList = new ArrayList<NewsDrawerItem>();

public NewsDrawerItem() {
}

public NewsDrawerItem(String Id, String title) {
    this.Id = Id;
    this.title = title;
}

public NewsDrawerItem(String Id, String title, String PId) {
    this.Id = Id;
    this.title = title;
    this.PId = PId;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return this.title;
}

public String getId() {
    return this.Id;
}

public String getPId() {
    return this.PId;
}


public int getIcon() {
    return this.icon;
}

public ArrayList<NewsDrawerItem> getChildItem() {
    System.out.println("CHILD_ITEM = "+childItemList);
    return childItemList;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public void setId(String Id) {
    this.Id = Id;
}

public void setPId(String PId) {
    this.PId = PId;
}

public void setIcon(int icon) {
    this.icon = icon;
}

public void setChildItem(ArrayList<NewsDrawerItem> childItemList) {
    this.childItemList = childItemList;
}
```

}

Comment: i believe you assume a click for exapdable Listview when it expands, you can use onGroupClicklistener yo see if you're group is clicked

Comment: yes I wrote that. but confused in how to identify if child element is empty or not ?

Comment: you would have to post how are you implementing you're expandable listview model from that you can easily tell if the child is empty or not

Comment: from your code what i can tell is that you can't read the child which is empty as it would be null if you try you might risk a null pointer error, what you can do is create a data model like parent and child for group and item respectively and make child a arraylist variable in parent class that way you can check you're group easily in Expandable adapter, if you want something for this i will give you some code

Comment: yes pankanj...i need some code. i tried alot for it but no hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this code you will see that child is associated with parent so for a given parent you can check if it it is null or empty with a given position of the parent in the list that way you can figure out what you have to do next if child list is empty

Child.java

```
public class Child {


private String _Title_child = "";

public String get_Title_child() {
    return _Title_child;
}

public void set_Title_child(String _Title_child) {
    this._Title_child = _Title_child;
}
}
```

Parent.java

```
public class Parent {

private int _icon_ID = 0;
private String _Title_parent = "";
private ArrayList<Child> _Children = null;

public int get_icon_ID() {
    return _icon_ID;
}

public void set_icon_ID(int _icon_ID) {
    this._icon_ID = _icon_ID;
}

public String get_Title_parent() {
    return _Title_parent;
}

public void set_Title_parent(String _Title_parent) {
    this._Title_parent = _Title_parent;
}

public ArrayList<Child> get_Children() {
    return _Children;
}

public void set_Children(ArrayList<Child> _Children) {
    this._Children = _Children;
}
}
```

Adapter

```
public class MyExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{

private Context _Context;
private ArrayList<Parent> _Parents;
private LayoutInflater _Inflater;
private static MyExpandableAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableAdapter();

private MyExpandableAdapter(){}

public static MyExpandableAdapter deInitialization(Context context, ArrayList<Parent> parents){
    adapter._Context = context;
    adapter._Parents = parents;
    adapter._Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(adapter._Context);
    return adapter;
}


@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return _Parents.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return _Parents.get(groupPosition).get_Children().size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return _Parents.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return _Parents.get(groupPosition).get_Children().get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = _Inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group,parent,false);
    }
    ImageView icon_Group = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_icon_group);
    TextView title_group = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_title_group);

    icon_Group.setImageResource(_Parents.get(groupPosition).get_icon_ID());
    title_group.setText(_Parents.get(groupPosition).get_Title_parent());

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView = _Inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
    }

    TextView title_child = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_title_child);
    title_child.setText(_Parents.get(groupPosition).get_Children().get(childPosition).get_Title_child());

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
}
```

list_group.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="4dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="40dip"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:id="@+id/imageView_icon_group"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_title_group"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:textSize="18dip"
    android:text="Parent Item"
    android:textColor="#c0000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_title_child"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14dip"
    android:text="Child Item"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `mainAcitivity` where you are setting adapter to the `expandableListView` as

```
expandableListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(headerList, hashMap);
        listViewExpandable.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
```

call its method [ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) inside that get count of child by passing groupPosition that will return count of childs related to the groupPosition you pass.
Here is a code snippet

```
listViewExpandable.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,
                                        long id) {

                Log.e("GroupClicked"," Position = " + groupPosition;

                int ChildCountWay1 = expandableListAdapter .getChildrenCount(groupPosition);
          // OR
                int childCountWay2 = parent.getExpandableListAdapter().getChildrenCount(groupPosition);
                if (childCountWay2<1) {
                    // do whatever you want
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
```